# Issue with links using page routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

I am using a `RouteTable` to register some routes for my site. Right now, it looks like this:

**Global.asax**

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    RemoteReaderPlugin.Current.AllowRemoteRequest += Current_AllowRemoteRequest;

    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    //routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    //Clan
    routes.MapPageRoute("","Clan/{address}","~/Clan/Default.aspx");
    routes.MapPageRoute("", "Clan/Register", "~/Clan/Register.aspx");
    routes.MapPageRoute("", "Member/GameRanking/{address}", "~/Member/GameRanking.aspx");

    //Member
    routes.MapPageRoute("", "Member/{address}", "~/Member/Default.aspx");
    routes.MapPageRoute("", "Member/Register", "~/Member/Register.aspx");
    routes.MapPageRoute("", "Member/GameRanking/{address}", "~/Member/GameRanking.aspx");

    //Site
    routes.MapPageRoute("", "{address}", "~/{address}.aspx");
    routes.MapPageRoute("", "{address}/{resource}", "~/{address}/{resource}.aspx");
}
```

This all works when I point the browser to `http://localhost:27950/OCDB/Default`.

But, when I point the browser to `http://localhost:27950/OCDB/`, then any link I click on leads to this error:

```
Server Error in '/OCDB' Application.

The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/OCDB/' is not allowed.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/OCDB/' is not allowed.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[HttpException (0x80004005): The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/OCDB/' is not allowed.]
   System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +2523961
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +301
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18034
```

Is there any way to fix this error? Or to force the browser to `/Default` before anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you replace this line :

```
routes.MapPageRoute("", "{address}", "~/{address}.aspx");
```

with

```
routes.MapPageRoute("", "{address}", "~/{address}.aspx", true, defaults: new RouteValueDictionary { { "address", "default" } });
```

Hope this will help